# ruby on rails loop : doesn't ouput data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following codes that works in the rails console

```
pages = Page.all
 pages.each do |i|
  p i.name
end
```

but when I want to do the same thing in a partial it only output the hole array of Pages but it's seems not entering in the loop block.

Comment: Post the code from the partial.

Comment: `<p><%= 
pages = Page.all
 pages.each do |i|
  p i.name
 end
%></p>`

Comment: `<%=` prints the output which is `pages` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you really going to print only name in the view use pluck instead of Page.all

```
<p>
  <% Page.pluck(:name).each do |name| %>
    <%= name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `view`:

```
<p>
  <% Page.all.each do |i| %>
    <%= i.name %>
    # <span><%= i.name %></span> # An alternative
  <% end %>
</p>
```